# Intuition behind Cumulative Accuracy Profile(CAP)

Tags: curves, cumulative-accuracy-profile

I am really having trouble understanding the intuition behind Cumulative Accuracy Profile(CAP) Curve. I mean where exactly does the CAP curve is used and how do you read the CAP curve? Parts of the CAP curve?

Could anyone explain in simple words (and maybe with an example) what is the Intuition behind Cumulative Accuracy Profile(CAP)?

Comment: Reasonable question (+1). I think you are a bit unlucky and got stuck in some terminology issues. Cumulative Accuracy Profile curve is the Cumulative Gains curve. Just it was named like that from a subset of Marketing people. Ignore the jargon. Please see my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279385); the CAP curve is *exactly* the same but instead of expressing it as "Gains" (ie. in terms of percentages) it is expressed in absolute numbers (i.e. in terms of items).